# Executing a .aspx webpage request in Godaddy windows Plesk Scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a hosted an Asp.net application on GoDaddy. I want to schedule some email alerts at a specific time, for that I have written code for sending Email Alerts in an aspx page.  I am calling this page through the Godaddy Scheduler using the below credentials

My arguments are as below to call the page

```
Executable : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Argument : -c "(new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://mydomainname.biz\MMM\EmailAlerts.aspx')"
```

But its giving error after scheduler is scheduling the alerts as

> At line:1 char:1
>   + (new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://mydomainname.biz\MMM\Emai ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Please let me know where I am making a mistake. Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Noor

Answer (score 0):

I changed the argument as below. Its working fine now.

Argument : -c "(new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://mydomainname.biz/MMM/EmailAlerts.aspx')"

Regards,
Noor